# Fill Missing value in Pandas Dataframe combined with Merge

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My dataframe has misaligned observations, that is the dates do not match because the columns are pairs of dates and values that were generated invidiually via API, like so:

```
data = {'Date.0': ['1/1/2022','1/2/2022', '1/3/2022','1/4/2022'], 'ABC Return': [11, 21, 31, 41], 'Date.1': ['1/1/2022','1/2/2022', '1/4/2022','1/5/2022'], 'XYZ Return': [12, 22, 42, 51] }
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I would like to fix this to get them aligned and fill missing values with 0 (or NaN or something):

```
data = {'Date.0': ['1/1/2022','1/2/2022', '1/3/2022','1/4/2022','1/5/2022'], 'ABC Return': [11, 21, 31, 41, np.NaN], 'Date.1': ['1/1/2022','1/2/2022', '1/3/2022', '1/4/2022','1/5/2022'], 'XYZ Return': [12, 22, np.NaN, 42, 51]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I have roughly 60 variables, and I haven't been able to come up with a scalable solution (other than merging them by hand in Excel). Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: Please note that there is no systematic pattern (except that the ending is the same "xxx Return") to the value column (I have changed it from var1 and var2 to ABC and XYZ.) The dates are numbered and thus do have a pattern, but slightly different, I have updated this (instead of data_var1 it is now Date.0, Date.1 etc.

The following worked, slightly modified solution from Nick, since my column names changed:

```
# get a list of var names
ticker_list = [col for col in df.columns if col.endswith('Return')]
dates = pd.DataFrame(pd.concat([df[f'Date.{v}'] for v in range(2)]).unique()).set_index(0)
date_counter = 0
dfs = list()
for v in tickers:
    dfs.append(dates.join(df[[f'Date.{date_counter}', v]].set_index(f'Date.{date_counter}')).fillna(np.NaN))
    date_counter = date_counter + 1 
out = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1).reset_index(names='date')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to do this (reliant on your column naming scheme in the question, you will need to adapt if the real dataframe doesn't use those names):

```py
# get a list of var names
vars = [col for col in df.columns if col.startswith('var')]
# make a dataframe with all the unique dates as its index
dates = pd.DataFrame(pd.concat([df[f'date_{v}'] for v in vars]).unique()).set_index(0)
# extract each of the date_var* and var* columns to a separate df
# and join to the list of dates, filling na with 0
dfs = [dates.join(df[[f'date_{v}', v]].set_index(f'date_{v}')).fillna(0) for v in vars]
# concatenate all the dfs together and reset the index
out = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1).reset_index(names='date')
```

Output (for your sample data):

```
       date  var1  var2
0  1/1/2022  11.0  12.0
1  1/2/2022  21.0  22.0
2  1/3/2022  31.0   0.0
3  1/4/2022  41.0  42.0
4  1/5/2022   0.0  51.0
```

**Edit**

Based on the changes to the question, this modification to the code should do what is required:

```py
ticker_cols = [col for col in df.columns if col.endswith('Return')]
date_cols = [col for col in df.columns if col.startswith('Date')]
dates = pd.DataFrame(pd.concat([df[date] for date in date_cols]).unique()).set_index(0)
dfs = [dates.join(df[[date, ticker]].set_index(date)).fillna(0) for date, ticker in zip(date_cols, ticker_cols)]
out = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1).reset_index(names='date')
```

Output:

```
       date  ABC Return  XYZ Return
0  1/1/2022        11.0        12.0
1  1/2/2022        21.0        22.0
2  1/3/2022        31.0         0.0
3  1/4/2022        41.0        42.0
4  1/5/2022         0.0        51.0
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, this worked on this min example, but I am not able to transfer it to my actual data because my value column does not actually follow a pattern (my mistake for not doing that correctly). See edit above. Would this approach still work if the value columns are just random names.

Comment: I have modified your first line to this:
vars = [col for col in df.columns if col.endswith('Return')]
that is as far as I got.

Comment: And I changed your 2nd line too: dates = pd.DataFrame(pd.concat([df[f'Date.{v}'] for v in range(50)]).unique()).set_index(0)
I have 50 date.x columns, that's why

Comment: Your 3rd line becomes:
dfs = [dates.join(df[[f'Date.{v}']].set_index(f'Date.{v}')).fillna(0) for v in range(50)]

Comment: But when I run pd.concat, I get this error:
InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects

Comment: I was able to make it work:
date_counter = 0
dfs = list()
for v in tickers:
    dfs.append(dates.join(df[[f'Date.{date_counter}', v]].set_index(f'Date.{date_counter}')).fillna(np.NaN))
    date_counter = date_counter + 1 
Thank you so much!!!!

Comment: @Tartaglia sorry I wasn't around to answer your questions - been a busy day today. I'm glad you got it working.

Comment: @Tartaglia I've edited my answer with fairly generic code which should work for your actual df.

Comment: No worries at, I appreciate you taking time to write up this solution in the first place. All the ingredients were there, I just had to slightly adjust it for my actual df because of the different naming. Great and easy to understand solution!!

Comment: @Tartaglia no worries - I'm glad I could help. It was an interesting problem.

Answer (score 2):

**Example**

```
data = {'date_var1': ['1/1/2022','1/2/2022', '1/3/2022','1/4/2022'], 'var1': [11, 21, 31, 41], 'date_var2': ['1/1/2022','1/2/2022', '1/4/2022','1/5/2022'], 'var2': [12, 22, 42, 51] }
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

`df`

```
    date_var1   var1    date_var2   var2
0   1/1/2022    11      1/1/2022    12
1   1/2/2022    21      1/2/2022    22
2   1/3/2022    31      1/4/2022    42
3   1/4/2022    41      1/5/2022    51
```

**Code**

use [pd.wide_to_long](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html)

```
df1 = (pd.wide_to_long(df.reset_index(), ['date_var', 'var'], i='index', j='')
.reset_index().pivot_table('var', index='date_var', columns='')
.add_prefix('var').fillna(0))
```

`df1`

```
            var1    var2
date_var        
1/1/2022    11.0    12.0
1/2/2022    21.0    22.0
1/3/2022    31.0    0.0
1/4/2022    41.0    42.0
1/5/2022    0.0     51.0
```

make 'date_var#' columns and align like `df`

```
n=2
(df1
 .assign(**{'date_var{}'.format(i + 1) : df1.index for i in range(n)})
 .reset_index(drop=True)
 .reindex(columns=df.columns))
```

`output`

```
    date_var1   var1    date_var2   var2
0   1/1/2022    11.0    1/1/2022    12.0
1   1/2/2022    21.0    1/2/2022    22.0
2   1/3/2022    31.0    1/3/2022    0.0
3   1/4/2022    41.0    1/4/2022    42.0
4   1/5/2022    0.0     1/5/2022    51.0
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, this worked on this min example, but I am not able to transfer it to my actual data because my value column does not actually follow a pattern (my mistake for not doing that correctly). See edit above. Would this approach still work if the value columns are just random names.